How to create new Seurat object from a part of UMAP clusters?
My task is to perform an analysis of T-cells in PBMC dataset. I received 9 clusters with the following code.
pbmc <- RunUMAP(pbmc, dims = 1:10)

DimPlot(pbmc, reduction = "umap")

Clusters 0,2,4 and 6 are T-cells and I want to extract them to new Seurat object in RStudio.
I tried using
clusters <- c(0, 2, 4, 6)

tcells <- pbmc %>% subset(Idents() %in% clusters)

but I received Error in FetchData()

The subset function takes an idents argument so you could do something like:
subset(pbmc, idents = c("0","2","4","6"))
also note that the cluster names are character not numeric.
The more general answer is that you can subset on any metadata column by doing
subset(object, subset = colname %in% values)
so in your case it would probably be
subset(pbmc, subset = seurat_clusters %in% c("0", "2", "4", "6"))
